# Worklight 6.2 Consumer Edition : Error in deploying worklight applications and adapters

Tags: ant, ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-server

I have build my project through ["build-all"](http://pastebin.com/3bdjiu9Z) Ant Task and I have deployed the war file using the  ["install"](http://pastebin.com/3bdjiu9Z) ant task. After Deployment through this I was getting "No Runtime Environment Found" message on the screen. But After removing following JNDI entries in ["server.xml"](http://pastebin.com/fuE17cD7) file the browse button appear on the screen:

```
<jndiEntry jndiName="MyProject/publicWorkLightProtocol" value='http'/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="MyProject/publicWorkLightPort" value='9080'/>
<jndiEntry jndiName="MyProject/ibm.worklight.admin.environmentid" value='WL_UAT_Config1'/>
```

Following message is also coming above browse button : `FWLSE0023E: application 'myProjecy' not found, please redeploy. [project MyProject]`

Then I tried to deployed my adapter and application files and Server is giving following errors on console :

```
[ERROR   ] FWLSE0228E: Failed to deploy the application deployable. Reason: null [project MyProject]
[ERROR   ] Preparation to deploy 'myProject' failed
java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERROR   ] Result: MyProject: WL_UAT_Server///1.2.3.4: ApplicationDeploymentException:java.lang.NullPointerException
[ERROR   ] Preparation to deploy adapter '' failed.
Missing xml file
[ERROR   ] Result: MyProject: WL_UAT_Server///1.2.3.4: RuntimeException:Missing xml file
```

However, If I use this ["server.xml"](http://pastebin.com/eS9LQfNr) file and deploy the war using ["deploy-war"](http://pastebin.com/3bdjiu9Z) ant task. Everything just works fine. Also, if I deploy everything on server through eclipse everything works  fine. Let me know if you guys need any more info over this.

Comment: Try the deployment process again. My guess is that the second error is due to the first error, which may originate due to not using an envId while deploying the administration war file.

Comment: @IdanAdar I am still getting the same error.

Comment: What guide are you following?

Comment: http://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/devref/r_ant_tasks_deploy_projects.html

Comment: @IdanAdar I am also getting following error as as soon as I open worklight console "FWLSE0023E: application 'myProject' not found, please redeploy. [project MyProject]"

Comment: This all stems from bad deployment. Start over, carefully read the instructions.

Comment: @IdanAdar I have repeated everything carefully even then I am getting the same error. However, if I deploy war manually then its working completely fine.

Comment: Edit the question with steps and details that you take when using the took.

Comment: I'll rather email you the whole build file, it would be easier. Once we reach the solution then I will update question.

Comment: No thanks. Remove from the file anything sensitive and then upload it to site like pastebin.com and share the URL.

Comment: @IdanAdar I have updated the question. Pls see if you can find something from it.

Comment: For reference, here is a diff between the two server.xml files: https://www.diffchecker.com/l2l0v4ti

Comment: @IdanAdar Yeah.. I already checked the difference. Configuration in  this file http://pastebin.com/fuE17cD7 is getting generated by "install" task (which, in my case, is not working).

Answer (score 0):

The class loader of the project WAR file is not set to parent last

```
<application context-root="/MyProject" id="MyProject" location="MyProject.war" name="MyProject" type="war">
    <classloader commonLibraryRef="worklight-6.2.0">
        <privateLibrary>
            <fileset dir="${wlp.user.dir}/shared/resources" includes="org.hsqldb.hsqldb_2.2.5.jar"/>
        </privateLibrary>
    </classloader>
</application>
```

It should -- see https://www-01.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/SSZH4A_6.2.0/com.ibm.worklight.deploy.doc/admin/t_configuring_liberty_profile_manually.html

Ant tasks do install the hsqldb library, which is not listed in the supported software for Worklight http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg27024838 .... This file was probably crafted manually related to the Worklight Install part.

Comment: after changing class loader as given in documentation, its giving me Runtime Synchronization Failes error now. Pls find log at http://pastebin.com/9wjGshcV